# Ошибка ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'back'

Tags: python

Я пишу программу которая при input 1, 2, 3 должна что то выводить а когда input будет back выводить начало. что ввел пользователь проверяется через if. но если в начале input я не ставлю int то вывод с числами не работает а если ставлю то вывод с back не работает что мне с этим делать

Comment: Не пытаться приводить слова к числам.

Comment: Так вы можете потом привести к int, уже после проверки на специальные слова, что вам мешает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так делайте все в свое время: сначала работайте с текстом, а когда надо - с числами

Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, то она может решаться таким способом:

```
text = input()

# проверяем на ввод "back"
if text == "back":
    # что-то делаем
else:
    # попытаемся перевести ввод пользователя в число
    try:
        num = int(text)

        # работаем с числом num
    except:
        # не получилось перевести - делаем что-то свое
```